# Phase transfer catalyzed Claisen condensation using sodium hydroxide or carbonate. Why?

Tags: aldol-reaction

I was wondering if there was any obvious reason why I wouldn't be able to conduct a Claisen condensation between phenylacetonitrile
and an ester like methyl benzoate under phase transfer conditions (ie. aliquat 336), and sodium hydroxide or potassium carbonate and if there would be any impediments to that reaction taking. Is it necessary for the reaction to be conducted anhydrous? Is carbonate better than hydroxide?

Here are some refences.
Synthesis of Glycidic Esters in a Two-Phase Solid-Liquid System
https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/doi/abs/10.1080/00397918209408010

REACTIONS OF PHENYLACETONITRILE DERIVATIVES WITH AROMATIC
NITROCOMPOUNDS IN BASIC MEDIA
https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4020(01)90658-1
https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0960-894X(01)00443-7
https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/doi.org/10.1039/B418156E

Comment: What solvent are you using for your organic phase?

Comment: Is toluene appropriate? either toluene or dimethylformamide, preferably the former.

Comment: Toluene should be fine. I have done phase transfer alkylations of phenylacetonitrile in two liquids phases (DCM/water) using TBAB/hydroxide which works well.

Comment: Waylander do you have confidence that If I use a alkyl ester instead of an aromatic ester, I would produce a ketone, under phase transfer conditions, I intend on using sodium hydroxide as an 50% aqueous solution perhaps,

Comment: The pKa of phenylacetonitrile in around 14. It it by so way the most acid site present so I see no great problem. The ketone product will readily deprotonate so some may go into the aq phase.